# htaccess find last name after slash to redirect to an other page

Tags: java, php, codeigniter, zend-framework, yii

I want from htaccess 
url like this example http://www.clubrowcreations.co.uk/marketing-mistakes-general/thank-you
all url end with (/thank-you) redirect to main url

how do i do from htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi guy i found the answer for it 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/thank-you$ page/45/thank-you.html [L]
this will direct all thank-you in the end url to page/45/thank-you.html page

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all urls that end in /thank-you to the main url you need to use a rewrite rule that:

1. matches the entire path for any url ending with "/thank-you"
2. replaces this with the "main url" (let's assume that it's "/index.html")

Here is the .htaccess fragment that does that:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .*/thank-you$ index.html [NC]